# Output video duration mismatch with GStreamer in C++

Tags: c++11, gstreamer

I'm trying to record a video from USB camera, encode and save it using GStreamer. Every 20 seconds I want to stop the video, change output name and restart capture/encoding.

I'll post a simplified version of my code, because it's quite long and irrelevant.

Additional details: 
`timer` keeps track of the elapsed time (in seconds).
`create_pip(j)` builds the following gst pipeline and appends j to the filename (like test_rgb_0.mp4, test_rgb_1.mp4 etc)

```
    "v4l2src ! video/x-raw, width=1280, height=720, framerate=30/1, format=RGB ! videoconvert ! omxh265enc bitrate=2000000 qp-range=35,51:35,51:-1,-1 vbv-size=1 iframeinterval=60 ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test_rgb.mp4 -e"
```

```
    // declarations and stuff
    // this for is just to have 3 different video files
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
        // create pipeline
        pipeline = gst_parse_launch(create_pip(j).c_str(),NULL);
        gst_element_set_state(pipeline,GST_STATE_PLAYING);
        timer.reset();        // reset timer to 0
        while(timer.elapsed()<=20){
            // do some other stuff, can be ignored
        }
        // stop stream and release pipeline
        gst_element_set_state(pipeline,GST_STATE_NULL);
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
    }
```

Everything works fine, output videos are 20-second long but vlc (or mediainfo) shows that the videos are 0 or 1 second long. If I open the video, it is actually 20-second long so the remaining time goes on negative numbers, (-19 or -20 seconds). Since the pipeline I created works fine on command line, I think that my program fails to save some metadata when closing the stream. I'm sorry but I'm fairly new to Gstreamer, what am I missing?

Comment: Well since the mux does not know about you are going ot begin a new file some meta data may be missing. Any reason you don't want to use `multifilesink` instead?

Comment: Or `splitmuxsink` even..

Comment: @FlorianZwoch I'm dumb, I completely forgot that `multifilesink` existed. I've just tried to build a new pipeline with it, but I still have the same problem. This is the pipeline I used: `"v4l2src ! video/x-raw, width=1280, height=720, framerate=30/1, format=RGB ! videoconvert ! omxh265enc bitrate=2000000 qp-range=35,51:35,51:-1,-1 vbv-size=1 iframeinterval=60 ! matroskamux ! multifilesink next-file=5 max-file-duration=20000000000 location=test_rgb_%02d.mp4 -e"`

Comment: I forgot to mention, I run into that same problem even if I launch the pipeline from command line with `gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! video/x-raw, width=1280, height=720, framerate=30/1, format=RGB ! videoconvert ! omxh265enc bitrate=2000000 qp-range=35,51:35,51:-1,-1 vbv-size=1 iframeinterval=60 ! matroskamux ! multifilesink next-file=5 max-file-duration=20000000000 location=test_rgb_%02d.mp4 -e`. It seems that `splitmuxsink` doesn't link to h265enc, but DOES work if I change encoder to h264 and produces 20-second long videos

Answer (score 0):

Oh I didn't realize you restart the whole pipeline. You need to send EOS through the pipeline I think instead of just setting its state to NULL.

The `-e` is specific to the `gst-launch-1.0` application. It is not part of the regular launch syntax I believe. You will have to do this yourself.

E.g.

```
// send EOS to pipeline
gst_element_send_event(pipeline, gst_event_new_eos());

// wait for the EOS to traverse the pipeline and is reported to the bus
GstBus *bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

[..]
```

I'm not sure with live sources though. Perhaps you need to tell v4l2src to send the EOS by itself instead of the pipeline as a whole. Or just the mp4mux? At least I'm pretty sure the mp4 mux needs an EOS at some point to finalize the file correctly.

Comment: Yes I was definitely missing the EOS event. I implemented your code and the first video works perfectly. But I'll have to tweak my code, because I get a "device not ready" error. I think the program tries to open the pipeline too early while it is still closing. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Could be that the device needs to settle first, you are right. But also make sure you are release all objects (releasing the bus after you acquire it etc). Then again if your goal is to capture continuously I would recommend to just keep it running and use `splitmuxsink`. I"m surprised it doesn't work with H.265 though, is that known or a bug(?)

Comment: Actually I think `mp4mux` may have specific requirements for H.265. Maybe inserting `h265parse` before `splitmuxsink` helps. Then again I don't see why the regular pipeline to mp4 would have worked..

Comment: Oh, because you cheated, using matroskamux but name it mp4! You can use matroskamux with splitmuxsink too if you set it right (defaults to mp4mux).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I used `splitmuxsink` and I added to the pipeline `h265parse` and `muxer=matroskamux`. Everything works, but my output files are 2 seconds shorter than what I set (e.g. if I set `max-size-time=10000000000` videos are 8-second long). What could the issue be?

Comment: This depends where the encoder puts Key-frames. Since you want to play back any segment standalone it needs to be cut at Key-Frames. You can adjust key-frame behavior in the encoder to some extend - but it is a quality/granularity trade-off.